# How to run grep in a shell script, but exclude $0

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a script to check if i have removed all my javascript debbugger statements.

the current line in the script is:

```
grep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude=$0 "debugger" .
```

when I run this script in the directory im in it always returns

```
./debugger-checker.sh:4:grep --color=auto -nr --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude=$0 "debugger" .
```

how can do you make grep exclude the shell script that is running it??

Comment: Given that the line of output you see doesn't match the line of the script you present, it would seem that (perhaps) you are looking at a different script than the one grep is matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
grep -R --exclude-dir=node_modules "debugger" . | grep -v $0
```